MiniKube ExternalName access issue
I went through following resources for a week, but of no use:

All the StackOverflow ExternalName access issues
Kubernetes ExternalName documentation
Many YouTube videos about ExternalName
Many YouTube videos about Kubernetes networking
Medium articles about how to access external database from a pod

Here is the problem:
On my local machine, I have docker container nginx running at port 8090. It is using image nginx:stable-perl. In chrome when I run http://192.168.56.1:8090, a Welcome to nginx! page appears. Note that 192.168.56.1 is my local machine IP.
On my local machine, I also have a pod running on minikube started using minikube start --driver=hyperv. The pod is running helloworld container, using image 'bhargavshah86/kube-test:v0.1'.
Here is pod:
PS C:\data\code\unleash> kubectl get pods
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
helloworld-8654c996c4-thjrf   1/1     Running   0          9m48s

I ran port-forward command
kubectl --namespace default port-forward helloworld-8654c996c4-thjrf 8090:8090

Here is my etc\hosts
192.168.56.1 my.web

Here is nslookup:
/usr/share/nginx/html # nslookup 192.168.56.1 8090
Server:    0.0.31.154
Address 1: 0.0.31.154

Name:      192.168.56.1
Address 1: 192.168.56.1 my.web

Now when I try to curl the host 192.168.56.1:8090 from pod container, it times out.
/usr/share/nginx/html # curl 192.168.56.1 8090
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.56.1 port 80: Operation timed out

If I curl externalName my-web, host is not resolve:
/usr/share/nginx/html # curl http://my-web:8090
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: my-web

With service name url, it does not work:
/usr/share/nginx/html # curl my-web.default.svc.cluster.local:8090
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: my-web.default.svc.cluster.local

Even telnet times out:
/usr/share/nginx/html # busybox-extras telnet 192.168.56.1 8090
telnet: can't connect to remote host (192.168.56.1): Operation timed out

I installed apk add postgresql-client to access a Postgres on my local machine, running at 192.168.56.1 port '5432`, but error occurs:
psql -h 192.168.56.1 -U postgres

curl to google.com works:
/usr/share/nginx/html # curl www.google.com
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en-PK"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title><script nonce="1i3Z2zYvpmrTvPimeEfy8g">(function(){var _g={kEI:'CQ0pZpuiG8vk2roP3ZmLmAo',kEXPI:'0,18167,774941,577370,2329773,698,361,302200,146403,29615,4998,13744,39064,2711,2872,2891,8349,34679,46357,1014,1,16916,89311,6636,7596,1,42157,2,16734,23024,6700,41942,24676,33064,2,2,1,6959,19673,8155,8860,14491,22435,9779,5864,36595,20198,73179,2266,764,15816,1804,7734,6626,32722,1634,13493,29971,546,12350,5210437,1347,1190,5992132,2839368,3,1,1,1,1,1,14,23,91,27982631,16672,43887,3,318,4,1281,3,2121778,2585,24112,23010663,2739,4636,8409,3321,4706,8637,17451,8666,5,1905,36870,1922,7288,1301,2370,4832,1575,2863,1679,9303,12953,2210,7970,213,391,7526,2891,2437,4501,5,5102,4,105,8678,155,13518,2323,1794,1139,2042,33,1915,4,4952,6009,4981,360,234,1265,3,611,419,709,1794,1954,123,32,389,10,2085,207,8740,827,9,36,3685,2410,3753,892,680,9,5182,110,1299,1173,5,248,53,1060,969,538,2168,610,132,183,23,184,121,385,1050,4,1,6,762,1009,4,123,1949,932,272,433,1986,660,464,446,2,1,14,1,303,5,11,1157,538,853,2,4,922,673,1598,361,24,5,208,362,435,319,1076,38,1119,26,3,38,188,285,759,213,179,760,3,129,2,93,349,1091,135,665,347,387,139,300,218,246,1,161,483,1218,884,303,802,309,1,3,447,5,338,936,705,1,366,84,75,66,926,460,785,871,654,69,477,2,1345,8,1289,41,351,1898,74,733,39,17,548,925,595,111,563,123,48,43,50,49,511,466,3,313,104,20,145,881,651,249,537,1,1910,16,717,141,400,184,3,136,837,206,299,434,69,43,171,15,193,66,4,2,3,49,258,321,312,198,848,2097,2513,21262213,365638,3,3769,4505,21,2163,379,2613,614,105',kBL:'_YbZ',kOPI:89978449};(function(){var a;(null==(a=window.google)?0:a.stvsc)?google.kEI=_g.kEI:window.google=_g;}).call(this);})();(function(){google.sn='webhp';google.kHL='en-PK';})();(function(){

Here is describe:
PS C:\data\code\unleash> kubectl describe svc/my-web
Name:              my-web
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ExternalName
IP Families:       <none>
IP:
IPs:               <none>
External Name:     192.168.56.1
Port:              <unset>  8090/TCP
TargetPort:        8090/TCP
Endpoints:         <none>
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

Here is minikube tunnel output:
PS C:\data\code\unleash> minikube tunnel --bind-address=192.168.56.1
W0424 19:34:25.670477   20364 main.go:291] Unable to resolve the current Docker CLI context "default": context "default": context not found: open C:\Users\srhusain\.docker\contexts\meta\37a8eec1ce19687d132fe29051dca629d164e2c4958ba141d5f4133a33f0688f\meta.json: The system cannot find the path specified.
E0424 19:34:29.903003   20364 out.go:453] unable to execute error getting ssh port: get port 22 for "minikube": hyperv container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube: exec: "hyperv": executable file not found in %PATH%
stdout:

stderr:
: template: error getting ssh port: get port 22 for "minikube": hyperv container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube: exec: "hyperv": executable file not found in %!P(string=index)ATH&{%!
(string=index of untyped nil)}stdout:

stderr:
:1:92: executing "error getting ssh port: get port 22 for \"minikube\": hyperv container inspect -f \"'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports \"22/tcp\") 0).HostPort}}'\" minikube: exec: \"hyperv\": executable file not found in %PATH%\nstdout:\n\nstderr:\n" at <index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp">: error calling %!s(MISSING): 
%!w(MISSING) - returning raw string.

❌  Exiting due to DRV_PORT_FORWARD: error getting ssh port: get port 22 for "minikube": hyperv container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp"
) 0).HostPort}}'" minikube: exec: "hyperv": executable file not found in %PATH%
stdout:

stderr:


╭─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                                                             │
│      If the above advice does not help, please let us know:                                               │
│      https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose                                             │
│                                                                                                             │
│    Please run `minikube logs --file=logs.txt` and attach logs.txt to the GitHub issue.                      │
│    Please also attach the following file to the GitHub issue:                                               │
│    - C:\Users\srhusain\AppData\Local\Temp\minikube_tunnel_df9325734b3fbaf9471c9c4a9cc1524d4e32b11a_0.log    │
│                                                                                                             │
╰─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

I tried with both my.web and 192.168.56.1:
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my.web
.
.
.

spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: 192.168.56.1

Here is complete YAML:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: helloworld
  labels:
    app: helloworld
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: helloworld
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: helloworld
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: helloworld
        image:  bhargavshah86/kube-test:v0.1
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: "1"
          requests:
            memory: 256Mi
            cpu: "0.2"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-web
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: 192.168.56.1
  ports:
  - port: 8090
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8090


Here are endpoints:
PS C:\data\code\unleash> kubectl get endpoints
NAME         ENDPOINTS             AGE
helloworld   10.244.0.11:8080      3h4m
kubernetes   172.18.112.240:8443   4h3m

Here are pods:
PS C:\data\code\unleash> kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
helloworld-8654c996c4-mm4m2   1/1     Running   0          20m   10.244.0.11   minikube   <none>           <none>

I was expecting curl will not time out and a Welcome to nginx! html is returned.

Check this out.

It turn out in my case, Windows Firewall was the issue. By turning off Windows Firewall for Domain, Public and Private and using host.minikube.internal I was able to access both nginx and postgres.
